# How to format LINQPad scripts properly in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-code, linqpad

When I open a LINQPad script (with the *.linq extension) in VS Code, it does not have any formatting. How can I enforce the VS Code to format and treat it as C# code?

Answer (score 1):

Follow the following steps:

1. Open the LINQPad script in VS Code.
2. At the bottom right of the screen, click on Plain Text

[image: click on Plain Text]

3. In the menu that just opened, select: Configure File Association for '.linq'

[image: select: Configure File Association for '.linq']...

4. Select "C#" or any other language that is your default LINQPad script language.

[image: Select "C#" or any other language that is your default LINQPad script language]